# Why is Android transliterating my Cyrillic language values to equivalent Latin values?

Tags: android

I have an issue with Serbian Cyrillic language in my app which have 14 different languages. Russian Cyrillic is working just fine.

For example, if user set the app to work in Serbian language, therefore strings.xml from values-sr should be read. And it does. However, output is in equivalent Latin script.

For example, in strings.xml there is a word:

```
<string name="Password"><DATA><![CDATA[Лозинка]]></DATA></string>
```

R.string.Password should display **Лозинка** but instead it is displaying transliterated word as **Lozinka**... all characters changed to Latin equivalents.

I have tried this on my Mate 20 Pro device. However, on Android simulator in all software versions is working just fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug specific to some Huawei models. If you set Serbian(Latin) as language in the phone settings, it transliterate all Cyrillic string resources to Latin. It also messes up other Cyrillic languages defined as string resources.